# Decide between Polyglossia and Babel in 2012

Tags: babel, polyglossia

Could someone summarize features which are (1) common and (2) different for the [`babel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) and [`polyglossia`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) packages? I know that `babel` 3.8 (current version) fails to run for some languages  (eg, Russian) under LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX (at least it was so 2 years ago). What will be the future of the `polyglossia` package if `babel` 3.9 (which is now [`babel-alpha`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-alpha)) will manage to work with XeLaTeX? Will be any sense to use `polyglossia` as a replacement of `babel` in that case?

**UPDATE**: I am sorry for mixing several questions in one post. Main question was about differences between `polyglossia` and `babel`. For example, `polyglossia` has options specific to some languages.

Comment: As of now, [sometimes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325102/37291) the outputs produced with `polyglossia` and `babel` may be noticeably different (in vertical spacing, for example, in the case of French).

Comment: A more recent comparison : [Decide between Polyglossia and Babel for LuaLaTeX in 2019](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482396/decide-between-polyglossia-and-babel-for-lualatex-in-2019)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The relationship between `babel` and `polyglossia` with respect to XeTeX is complicated. The general rule of thumb is that if the babel `.ldf` file uses non-Latin scripts, then you should use `polyglossia` and generally can't use `babel` but if it assumes Latin scripts, you may still be able to use `babel`. With respect to your specific question, about Russian, it's obviously possible to write `babel` `.ldf` files that work with both engines, but for most of the non Latin scripts, this will not have been done and `polyglossia` will still be required.

The issues with Cyrillic are arguably less complicated than those using RTL scripts such as Hebrew and Arabic (as alluded to in @egreg's comment). Other scripts such as for Hindi also pose special problems for which pdfLaTeX is unlikely to be a choice. So `polyglossia` will remain required for those scripts which independently depend on XeLaTeX.

In 2013, Javier Bezos released a new version `babel` which (among other things) provides better support for UTF-8 engines such as XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.  This means that the differences between `babel` and `polyglossia` for most Latin script based languages will be minimal, but for RTL languages and non-Latin script languages generally, `polyglossia` support may be a better choice. The current version of `babel` (3.9 at time of writing) provides "minimal support for XeTeX and LuaTeX".

Comment: Moreover, `bidi` integrates with `polyglossia`

Comment: Indeed. such Russian.ldf has been already written. See http://ctan.org/pkg/russian.

Comment: Can you use both? Suppose that you wanted to write a document in Welsh about Hebrew, for example. Welsh requires babel but Hebrew requires polyglossia. Or is this kind of combination just not supported?

Comment: Polyglossia now has more correct support for Welsh (and more extensive) than Babel. So you can write about Hebrew in Welsh. (At least, I assume you can since you're a linguist.) It is apparently excruciatingly difficult to get mistakes in Babel's language files corrected, whereas it is apparently quite straightforward in Polyglossia ;).

Comment: New versions for `welsh`, `spanish` and `vietnamese` for `babel` are on the way, and they will be available very likely in a few weeks. In the near future (I'm working very actively) I presume babel 3.10 will be out (I hope before Christmas, but one never knows).

Comment: @JavierBezos Good to know. And feel free to edit my answer if you think I've misrepresented `babel` at all.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, `polyglossia` is intended to be a replacement of `babel` for `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: But why I would need `polyglossia` if `babel` will work with `xelatex`? In particular, the new russian LDF (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/russian) makes it possible to use `babel` with either of the existing latex engines, including xelatex.

Comment: @Igor Kotelnikov: who knows what will happen?  the current work aims to process the (large) backlog of babel error reports.  whether this work will leave us with a babel that works with unicode input (and things like bidi) remains to be seen.  so your question is (as yet) not answerable, i fear.