# Lualatex error with polyglossia's \setotherlanguages and ntheorem

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, ntheorem

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44701/2595
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[greek,danish,english]{babel}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{english}
  \setotherlanguages{greek,danish} %% (A): causes "Command \proofname already defined."; do it after ntheorem?
  \ifXeTeX
    \usepackage{xltxtra}
  \else
    \usepackage{luatextra}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\fi

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
% \ifPDFTeX \else %% (B):
%   \setotherlanguages{greek,swedish} % polyglossia leftover; causes "Command \greek already defined."
% \fi

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `lualatex --file-line-error test.tex`, I get:

```
...
(/media/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntheorem/ntheorem.sty
Style `ntheorem', Version 1.33 <2011/08/15>
(/media/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)

/media/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntheorem/ntheorem.sty:1175: 
LaTeX Error: Command \proofname already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1175 \ProcessOptions\relax

?
```

After seeing "Command \proofname already defined", I tried to look a bit in `polyglossia.dtx`:

```bash
$ awk 'BEGIN{tdo=0;} 
  /captions(danish|swedish|.*greek)/ {print $0; tdo=1;}     
  /proofname/{if(tdo==1){print $0; tdo=0;}}
' `kpsewhich polyglossia.dtx` 

\def\captionsdanish{%
  \def\proofname{Bevis}%
\def\captionsgreek{\monogreekcaptions}%
    \def\captionsgreek{\polygreekcaptions}%
      \def\captionsgreek{\ancientgreekcaptions}%
      \def\captionsgreek{\monogreekcaptions}%
   \def\proofname{Απόδειξη}%
\def\captionsswedish{%
  \def\proofname{Bevis}%
```

... and indeed, all languages redefine `\proofname`; so my first idea was to replace (A) with (B) in the MWE - but that results with "Command \greek already defined.".

Now this is the funny thing: this error occurs in (A) **only** when `{greek,danish}` is used in `\setotherlanguages` - it does *not* occur for, say, `{greek,swedish}` or just `{greek}`! (<sub>Note that the error in (B) occurs also for Swedish</sub>)

Best I could do here, was to compare the polyglossia files for Danish and Swedish, and see if there is a difference - and I tried

```
meld `kpsewhich gloss-swedish.ldf` `kpsewhich gloss-danish.ldf`
```

... and I cannot see any significant difference?!

So my question is - how can I use `polyglossia` with `\setotherlanguages{greek,danish}` without crashing?

Comment: Well I would use `\usepackage[greek,danish,english]{babel}` for xelatex and lualatex too. The main difference between danish and swedish is imho the handling of the dates.

Comment: Thanks for that @UlrikeFischer - but I thought, `polyglossia` was replacement for `babel`? Then again, I just found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88481/polyglossia-vs-babel, where it mentions: "_The relationship between babel and polyglossia with respect to XeTeX is complicated. The general rule of thumb is that if the babel .ldf file uses non-Latin scripts, then you should use polyglossia and generally can't use babel but if it assumes Latin scripts, you may still be able to use babel_". So, I guess (haven't tested) here Greek would be a problem?

Comment: Your quote is from 2012. Things have changed and babel is moving towards unicode and xelatex/lualatex. If you look in greek.ldf you will see that it contains suitable code for e.g. EU1 and EU2 font encodings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `polyglossia` then reset `\proofname` to undefined:

```
[...]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\proofname\relax
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @Herbert - but would that (in principle) interfere with proof names should the language be switched later on in the document?

Comment: sure, it is your decision which version of `\proofname` you want to use. But it is no problem to use `\addtocaptions<language>{\def\proofname{...}}`

Comment: Thanks again, @Herbert - I just discovered that this may be due to a syntax error in `gloss-danish.ldf` (see my answer posting below)... which means, that if I don't want to hack `gloss-danish.ldf`, indeed the answer is to `\relax`, as you suggested. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got close to why this is happening; I've tried tracing:

```
...
\usepackage{trace}
...
  \traceon
  \setotherlanguages{greek,danish} %% (A): causes "Command \proofname already defined."; do it after ntheorem?
  \traceoff
...
```

.. and comparing the outputs for `{greek,danish}` and `{greek,swedish}`. For Swedish, the relevant trace is:

```
{blank space  }
{\par}
{\def}
{changing \captionsswedish=undefined}
{into \captionsswedish=macro:->\def \refname {Referenser}\def \abstractname \ETC
.}
{blank space  }
{\par}
{\def}
{changing \dateswedish=undefined}
{into \dateswedish=macro:->\def \today {\number \day ~\ifcase \ETC.}
{blank space  }
{\par}
{\endinput}
)
{\catcode}
```

... and for Danish, it is:

```
{blank space  }
{\par}
{\def}
{changing \captionsdanish=undefined}
{into \captionsdanish=macro:->\def \prefacename {Forord}\def \refname \ETC.}
{\def}
{changing \proofname=undefined}
{into \proofname=macro:->Bevis}
{\def}
{changing \glossaryname=undefined}
{into \glossaryname=macro:->Gloseliste}
{\def}
{changing \today=macro:->\ifcase \month \or January\or Fe\ETC.}
{into \today=macro:->\number \day .~\ifcase \month \or \ETC.}
{blank space  }
{\par}
{\endinput}
)
{\catcode}
```

Somehow, besides `\captionsdanish`, this code path also manages to def `\proofname`, `\glossaryname` and `\today`. Why? Let's compare the .ldf files; `gloss-swedish.ldf` has:

```
\def\captionsswedish{%
...
  \def\proofname{Bevis}%
  \def\glossaryname{Ordlista}%
  }

\def\dateswedish{%   
  \def\today{%
... }%
    }
```

... while `gloss-danish.ldf` has:

```
\def\captionsdanish{%
...
  \def\alsoname{Se også}}% <--- !!
  \def\proofname{Bevis}%
  \def\glossaryname{Gloseliste}%
  \def\today{\number\day.~\ifcase\month\or
...}
```

If you see closely, the `\def\alsoname` closes with *two* closing braces `}}`, and the second one thus closes `\captionsdanish`, and leaves `\def`s for `\proofname`, `\glossaryname` and `\today` "bare" on the "root level"; and so when this file executes, they execute!

As far as I can see in `gloss-english.ldf`'s `\captionsenglish` - it is set up the same way `\captionsswedish` is; so I guess that is a syntax error in `\captionsdanish`. So, I guess, to really fix the error here, one has to intervene in `gloss-danish.ldf`. Version-wise, for future reference, I have these versions that showed this problem:

```bash
$ grep '\ProvidesPackage' $(kpsewhich polyglossia.sty)
\ProvidesPackage{polyglossia}[2014/05/21 v1.33.5

$ lualatex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014) (rev 4971)
```

Comment: Yes the two braces are an error, the brace should be behind the \def\today. You should make a bug report.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer - should that be `polyglossia`'s author, or http://latex-project.org/bugs-upload.html ? Cheers!

Comment: That's a polyglossia file.

Comment: I have submitted the issue with a suggestion for the fix: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/85

Comment: Thanks, @UlrikeFischer - after some grepping, I found that `kpsewhich polyglossia.dtx` contains a reference to GitHub, where I don't have an account yet, and would have been a problem to get soon - so @egreg, many thanks for the report! Cheers!

Comment: @egreg: You should also mention that one of the braces after `\def\alsoname{Se også}}%` should move down.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fixed