# Future of babel and polyglossia

Tags: babel, best-practices, polyglossia

Lately I've been trying both `babel` and `polyglossia` against each other to see if there are any advantages either way. But to my untrained eye there is no significant difference in regards to output between the two.

While [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88481/polyglossia-vs-babel) is giving a good overview on the status quo I'm interested in the current "trend":

Where is the future going? `babel` or `polyglossia`?

Comment: Related: [Polyglossia vs Babel](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88481)

Comment: Polyglossia has better support for Welsh. Not just better: Babel's uses characters which do not exist in Welsh, as do both `datetime` and `datetime2`.

Comment: I've updated my answer in [Polyglossia vs Babel](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88481) to reflect the most recent `babel`.

Comment: I don't think the question is answerable, it's like asking if the future is memoir or koma or if it's latex or context. Who knows what the future holds?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I believe this is not a dupe, especially in light of the current answers to the other question. There are definitely advantages and disadvantages to using each of the packages (at least for some bidirectional languages).

Comment: @einpoklum This question doesn't ask for advantages/disadvantages (that is the other question) it asks "where is the future going" as such it would be closed as "opinion based" if it wasn't closed as a dup.