# Two versions from same tex file

Tags: conditionals, versions

I'm writing a LaTeX text, but I need two versions of the same text, one normal and one with some more comments inside the text. How can I write both the versions using the same TEX file?

To be more clear I would like to obtain for example these two versions:

> ...first simple version...
>
> ...first simple version *with some more comments is now second version*...

And I would like for both of them the code to be something like:

```
...first simple version \secondversion{with some more comments is now second version}....
```

So that if I change a flag at the beginning of my TEX file I can obtain either the first or the second version.

Comment: In one version `\newcommand\secondversion[1]{}` and in the other, `\newcommand\secondversion[1]{#1}`.  Naturally, the 2nd version could also present `#1` in italics or color, or something else, if desired.

Comment: Where are the comments going to appear? What kind of text? Long, short?

Comment: IMO, the key is to use `\jobname`.   Here is what i did to have two different PDFs from the same source when debugging some inconsistent behavior: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325102/37291.

Comment: I'd use conditionals and `\jobname` (as I did here): http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71559/8528

Comment: Please note that unless your supply the `-jobname` argument to `pdflatex`, your second version will overwrite the first version, unless you move the first version manually before compiling the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using a flag. You can set the flag in the preamble, change it on the fly in the document if you wish.

With a little more work you could set the flag on the compile command line without having to edit the file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{vtwo}

% set status globally in the preamble
\togglefalse{vtwo}

\newcommand{\secondversion}[1]{%
\iftoggle{vtwo}{%
#1
}
% else
{}
}

\begin{document}

...first simple version \secondversion{with some more comments is now
  second version}....

% change status locally if you wish
\toggletrue{vtwo}

...first simple version \secondversion{with some more comments is now
  second version}....

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various packages that do precisely this. I use [versions](https://ctan.org/pkg/versions). In its documentation one can find a comparison to other packages. Below there is a minimum usage example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{versions}

\includeversion{abridged}
\excludeversion{unabridged}
\excludeversion{redact}
\begin{document}
Text for the \begin{abridged}short\end{abridged}\begin{unabridged}long and really longwinded, opaque and boring\end{unabridged} version of the paper. Punctuation works correctly\begin{unabridged}because sphack is used\end{unabridged}.
\begin{comment} This is deleted by default. \end{comment}
\begin{redact}This information was withdrawn\end{redact}
\end{document}
```

One has to pay attention not to leave blank spaces or add newline, for example, before the `\begin{abridged}` to get the proper spacing between word.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution that relies on inspecting `\jobname`.

The source file:

```latex
% source.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}  % for `\ifstrequal`

%% NOTE: i do not know how this works (how `\expandafter` works),
%%   but it works
\newcommand{\secondVsFirstVersion}[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\jobname}{second-version}{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand{\mainversion}[1]{\secondVsFirstVersion{}{#1}}
\newcommand{\secondversion}[1]{\secondVsFirstVersion{#1}{}}

\begin{document}
  ...first simple version \secondversion{with some more comments is now second version}....

  Moreover, \mainversion{this will appear only in the main version,}
  \secondVsFirstVersion{this will appear only in the second version}{
  and this only in the first again}.
\end{document}
```

To obtain the main version of the output, run

```bash
pdflatex -jobname='main-version' source.tex
```

(or just `pdflatex source.tex`).
To obtain the second, run

```bash
pdflatex -jobname='second-version' source.tex
```

Alternatively, create two hard links to this file called `main-version.tex` and `second-version.tex` and compile them as usual, without `-jobname` parameter.

IMO even better is to use a makefile with `latexmk`:

```
# Makefile

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

.PHONY: all
all: v1 v2

.PHONY: v1
v1: main-version.pdf

.PHONY: v2
v2: second-version.pdf

main-version.pdf: source.tex
    latexmk -pdf -jobname='main-version' '$<'

second-version.pdf: source.tex
    latexmk -pdf -jobname='second-version' '$<'

.PHONY: mostlyclean
mostlyclean:
    rm -f *.log

.PHONY: clean
clean: mostlyclean
    rm -f *.aux *.out *.toc *.fdb_latexmk *.fls

.PHONY: distclean
distclean: clean
    rm -f main-version.pdf second-version.pdf
```

Then to get both versions at once simply run `make` in the source directory.