# BibLaTeX: autolang=hyphen causing translation of key terms

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

I am writing a multilingual document and want bibliography entries properly hyphenated for their language. I do not want to translate terms in the bibliography like "in", "p.", and "edited by". As I read the BibLaTeX documentation, `autolang=hyphen` should do this, and it seems to me that it worked in the past, but now it also causes the translation of terms used in the bibliography, like "pp." to "S." for a German entry, which is what I would expect from `autolang=other`. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,autolang=hyphen,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Here I cite Sigfridsson\autocite{sigfridsson} and Spiegelberg\autocite{spiegelberg}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The example bibliography entries use `langid` to specify the language ("american" and "german" respectively). I get this (with similar results in the footnotes):

[image]

**Update:** since the problem was identified as a bug, I add some version numbers in case anyone reads this in the future: BibLaTeX 3.7, Polyglossia 1.42.4.

Comment: Unfortunately, `polygossia` support is shaky it best. If you don't need any of `polyglossia`'s special features you might be better of using `babel` instead.

Comment: I have a long document that sometimes quotes texts in non-Latin scripts, so I'm using XeLaTeX. I'm using `polyglossia` because I understood that it should be used instead of `babel` with XeLaTeX. Am I mistaken? Since the primary language is English, all I really want from `babel` or `polyglossia` is hyphenation: I don't need translations of dates or terms used by LaTeX.

Comment: If you are using non-Latin scripts you are indeed often better of with `polyglossia`. I have not that much experience with `polyglossia`/`babel` on Xe/LuaLaTeX, but I'm lead to believe that even though generally `polyglossia` is 'preferred' sometimes `babel` is good enough (cf [`babel` vs. `polyglossia`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88481/35864)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Update** `polyglossia` support in `biblatex` should be functionally equivalent to `babel` support in `biblatex` 3.14 (or above) and `polyglossia` 1.46 (or above).

At the moment `polyglossia` support in `biblatex` is still quite shaky. Language version detection (`american` vs. `british`) does not work at all right now.

The environment used with `autolang=hyphen` is `hyphenrules`, which needs an exception when processed by `biblatex`'s `polyglossia` interface.
This is addressed in [issue #564 on the github bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/564).

Things should work as expected again in the upcoming release.
If you don't need `polyglossia` features, you can always switch to `babel`. Currently `babel` support is more mature and stable.

Comment: What do you mean by "`hyphenrules`, which is not currently supported by polyglossia"? `hyphenrules` is part of the kernel. It is defined even without babel or polyglossia.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah yes, sorry I was mistaken in my analysis. I have edited the answer and will do some more investigation, which will probably lead to an issue in the github repository.

Comment: Good. I don't have the time to investigate but I had the impression that it should be possible to get autolang=hyphen working -- if needed with some manual translation command "\declarealiaslangidname{american}{british}" if automatic detection is too complicated.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you can find the time I would appreciate you having a look at my proposed solution in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/564. I would very much value any input you have. Also if you have any more ideas for proper polyglossia support that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Well my general view point is, that some language support should go in the kernel.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That would of course be nice, but we have to deal with the status quo. The first problem for `biblatex` is that `babel` and `polyglossia` don't have a standardised (or rather the same) interface. Language support seems a bit `babel`-centric at the moment.