# Language settings (fancyref) with fontspec and polyglossia

Tags: fontspec, german, fancyref

I have problems getting `fancyref` to properly work for German together with the fontspec/polyglossia set-up.

This is the bare set-up without any language settings:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyref}

\begin{document}
Das ist ein deutscher Text
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    Das soll eine Abbildung sein
    \label{fig:sample}
    \caption{Beispiel-Abbildung}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

Das ist die zweite Seite mit einem Verweis auf \fref{fig:sample}.
\end{document}
```

The interesting thing is and will be the result of the `fref` which refers to the figure "on the preceding page".

In this initial stage the figure is numbered as "Figure 1" and the reference reads "figure   on the preceding page".

Adding

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
```

will change the caption to "Abbildung 1" (which is correct) and the reference to "abbildung   on the preceding page". Note the lowercase "a" in "abbildung", which is not correct, although it's notable that the reference uses the German word at all.

According to the `fancyref` manual this should be set to German with

```
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[german]{fancyref}
```

However, this results a) in the error message "! You haven't defined the language [ yet." and b) the text "]german" to be included at the beginning of the document.

If I remove `\setmainlanguage{german}` the reference reads "figure auf der vorherigen Seite".

If I remove `\usepackage{german}` it reads "Abbildung on the preceding page"

I am completely confused about all this. What do I need for a German document with LuaLaTeX and `fontspec` and German `fancyref` references?

Comment: The package `german` is obsolete and should not be used in newer documents.

Comment: This is what I suspected, especially given that `fancyref`'s manual is from 1999. However, without it (at least with my attempts so far) `fancyref` will not use the German labels. It will translate "figure" with "Abbildung" but not "on the preceding page" (and all other reference texts).

Comment: `\usepackage[german]{babel}\usepackage[german]{fancyref}` works (I would prefer babel anyway), but the problem is that fancyref doesn't have declarations for ngerman, so you would have to add them. Using some newer package as egreg suggested is certainly better.

Comment: I thought that using `babel` together with `fontspec` was obsolete? That's obviously  not true? However, I'll have a look at the newer package(s), even if that means to review >150 pages of an existing document.

Comment: @uli_1973 - It is definitely *not* true that using `babel` together with `fontspec` is obsolete. Several years ago (5, maybe, and probably more), there was a phase when `babel` and `luatex` didn't get along. However, unless your TeX distribution is positively ancient, this should be no longer be of any concern.

Comment: So what would be the arguments for using `babel` vs. `polyglossia` nowadays. Using `luatex` and `fontspec` is a prerequisite but the others not. I'm using not the latest TeXLive but that from my distro, which is `LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)`, so rather current.

Comment: `polyglossia` development has stalled recently (https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues) there was a maintenance release for TeX live 2018 that included outstanding pull requests, but there has not been any real activity by the maintainer to fix other bugs or enhance features since 2016. `babel` development picked up speed again a while ago and even if the current maintainer has to leave it, the package is so important that it will probably have to be maintained by some emergency committee if that happens. Many packages that need localisation features work together well with `babel`

Comment: ... but might have issues with `polyglossia` (especially the variant detection with `polyglossia` is tricky). If you stick to Western European languages (certainly German, English, French, ...) `babel` is IMHO certainly preferable to `polyglossia`. If you need complicated RTL scripts `polyglossia` might have a bit of an advantage still, but `babel` is trying to bridge that gap. Unfortunately our standard answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88481/35864 might be a bit behind current developments.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. So can I assume that the deficiencies of `babel` regarding UTF-8 input that are mentioned in the "standard answer" and comments in 2012 and 2015 have become obsolete by now? I'm reviewing the infrastructure (originally put together in 2013 when I was starting with LaTeX) for a thesis and want to do things right now (to the extent this is possible ;-) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing: `\label` has to go *after* `\caption`.

The “proper” solution is to use the language option for `fancyref`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german]{fancyref}

\setmainlanguage{german}

\begin{document}

Das ist ein deutscher Text
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    Das soll eine Abbildung sein
    \caption{Beispiel-Abbildung}
    \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

Das ist die zweite Seite mit einem Verweis auf \fref{fig:sample}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd use `varioref` and `cleveref`, though.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\setmainlanguage{german}

\begin{document}

Das ist ein deutscher Text
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    Das soll eine Abbildung sein
    \caption{Beispiel-Abbildung}
    \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

Das ist die zweite Seite mit einem Verweis auf \vref{fig:sample}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: > The “proper” solution is to use the language option for fancyref < This is indeed one of the things I tried. However, the deciding difference between my attempt and your solution is that you use `\setmainlanguage` *after* loading fancyref.

Comment: What is the exact advantage of using `varioref` *and* `cleveref` in combination?

Comment: @uli_1973 - I'd say that using `varioref` and `cleveref` has three main advantages over using `fancyref`. First, the packages are still maintained and updated regularly; `fancyref` was last updated in 1999. Second, the `varioref` and `cleveref` packages know lots of cross-referenceable objects; the `fancyref` package only knows about 7 types (`chap`, `sec`, `eq`, `fig`, `tab`, `enum`, and `fn`) by default. Third, it's not essential (though it doesn't hurt either...) to use the `fig:` prefix for `figure` labels, the `tab:` prefix for `table` labels, the `eq:` prefix for equation labels, etc.

Comment: Thank you, but again: what's the reason to use *both* packages? Shouldn't I then simply use `cleveref`?

Comment: @uli_1973 `varioref` implements the phrases “in the next page” and so on.

Comment: @egreg so `cleveref` alone does *not* have these phrases, or implicitly requires `varioref`?

Comment: @uli_1973 If `varioref` is loaded, then `\cleveref` changes `\vref` to be as you see in the printout.